# The scanner works on a single user, the rest of users cannot use it

Tags: gnome, hp, users, 20.04, scanner

I am having problems allowing all users to use the scanner (HP deskjet 2632) connected through the wifi. One of the administrator users can use it without any problem. But the other two cannot use it, not even putting in the terminal of another administrator user `sudo xsane` I can scan the messages of the terminal in this case they are:

```
(xsane:2552): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 12:36:22.490: IA__gdk_drawable_unref: assertion 'GDK_IS_DRAWABLE (drawable)' failed
(xsane:2552): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 12:36:22.490: IA__gdk_drawable_unref: assertion 'GDK_IS_DRAWABLE (drawable)' failed
Capability : [(null)]
Capability : [image/jpeg]
Capability : [image/jpeg]
[xsane] ERROR: xsane-startimage not found. Looks like xsane is not installed correct.
```

To the `xsane` command it responds

```
(xsane:2651): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 12:42:48.511: IA__gdk_drawable_unref: assertion 'GDK_IS_DRAWABLE (drawable)' failed
(xsane:2651): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 12:42:48.511: IA__gdk_drawable_unref: assertion 'GDK_IS_DRAWABLE (drawable)' failed
Capability : [(null)]
Capability : [image/jpeg]
Capability : [image/jpeg]
[xsane] ERROR: xsane-startimage not found. Looks like xsane is not installed correct.
double free or corruption (out)
Abortado (`core' generado).
```

The programs I have installed are: Ubuntu 20.04, the snap hplip-printer-application 0.0.2 and xsane 0.999-8ubuntu2.

After the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/sane/xsane
sudo ln -t /usr/share/sane/xsane /usr/share/doc/xsane-common/*.pnm /usr/share/doc/xsane-common/*.rc /usr/share/doc/xsane-common/*.xpm
```

I get to see the preview window but it doesn't scan. `Xsane` now says:

```
Capability : [(null)]
Capability : [image/jpeg]
Capability : [image/jpeg]
double free or corruption (out)
Abortado (`core' generado)
```

I imagine it is a permission issue because a user uses it without problems, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe users need to be a member of the "scanner" group to be able to run sane, xsane, etc. Try using `adduser <username> scanner` to add the user to the "scanner" group. If it works I'll post it as an answer :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying, the scanner does not work after `sudo adduser yo scanner`, restart the computer. After the test I have deleted the scanner group.
I have also tried `sudo adduser yo uno`
leaving the groups,
`yo: yo adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare uno
uno: uno sudo`
It doesn't work on user yo, it works on user uno.